# Local page links (<a href='#' />) aren't working with HashRouter

Tags: html, reactjs, react-router, routes, react-router-dom

I wanted to add multiple pages to my React website so I started using the HashRouter import from react-router-dom. Since then only my main page loads and I am no longer able to use local links in the page. I can't redirect the user to specific areas on the main page which i used to be able to do before I started using the Router import. This website also uses github pages if that affects anything.

I am currently using the `<a>` tags like this:

```
<a className="nav-link" href="/#about-me">
  About Me
</a>
```

with the URL appearing as this with no content below it

```
http://localhost:3000/#about-me
```

I have also tried using the `<Link>` tag but it just ends up reloading the page.

```
<Link className="nav-link" to="/#about-me">
  About Me
</Link>
```

With this URL appearing instead:

```
http://localhost:3000/#/#about-me
```

**How do I get my page to scroll down to the id rather than reload or load a blank page?**

Main code snippets for reference:

**Home.js snippet**

```
const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div className='main'>
      <section className='section-welcome'>
        <Introduction />
      </section>
      <section id='about-me' className='section-about-me'>
        <AboutMe />
      </section>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

**Main.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import Home from './Pages/Home.js';
import NoPage from './Pages/NoPage.js';

const Main = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path='/' element={<Home />}></Route>
      <Route path="*" element={<NoPage />} />
    </Routes>
  );
}

export default Main;
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { HashRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
      <App /> {/* The various pages will be displayed by the `Main` component. */}
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Comment: If you're already on the page containing both the anchor (`<a>` tag) and the element with the nominated `id` or `name` attribute, try removing the leading `/`, eg `<a href="#about-me">`

Comment: `react-router-dom@6` doesn't handle hash links. You can revert to RRDv5 and use [react-router-hash-link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-hash-link), or read the hash from the receiving component and scroll that element into view. Since it seems like you are trying to link to sections already on the page use a raw anchor tag and link to the section sans the leading slash, i.e. like `<a href="#about-me">`.

Comment: removing the ```/``` doesnt seem to do anything, and I am having trouble importing  react-router-hash-link

Comment: sorry, I mis-typed that, I updated the question to show the full situation

Comment: Have you tried using the `BrowserRouter` instead? You can get around direct links using the Github pages 404 page

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with how the code runs with GitHub pages, not the references.

Currently, whenever a link is clicked in the NavBar the website tries to load the URL as `root/{href from <a> tag}`. This conflicts with GitHub pages as it searches links under the githubname.github.io/project-name/ and the program is trying to display githubname.github.io/#.

In order to fix this, you need to add a basename in the `<Router>` tag which forces the page to load at /project-name/#.

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { HashRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
      <App /> {/* The various pages will be displayed by the `Main` component. */}
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

**Relevant Links for more info**

https://maximorlov.com/deploying-to-github-pages-dont-forget-to-fix-your-links/

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#building-for-relative-paths