# Github Pages is not loading subpage even though url is correct

Tags: html, reactjs, react-router, github-pages

I am creating a multipage website using React and hosting it on Github pages. The website loads perfectly fine on localhost, but runs into trouble on Github pages when trying to enter a subpage.

The main page displays on Github Pages, but when the subpage link is clicked, Github pages displays the error 404 page.

```
404
File not found

The site configured at this address does not contain the requested file.
```

Although this error is shown the URL displays the same way the local host displays it.

**Main Page**

```
LocalHost: http://localhost:3000/my-website/ ** Runs Fine **
Github: https://myname.github.io/my-website/ ** Runs Fine **
```

**Sub Page**

```
LocalHost: http://localhost:3000/my-website/project ** Runs Fine **
Github: https://myname.github.io/my-website/project ** Runs into Error **
```

Relevant Code:

**Home.js** snippet

```
<div>
  <a href='/my-website/project'>
    <img alt='Project 1' src={Sunset} />
  </a>
</div>
```

**Main.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import Home from './Pages/Home.js';
import Project from './Pages/Project.js';
import NoPage from './Pages/NoPage.js';

const Main = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path='/' element={<Home />}></Route>
      <Route path='/project' element={<Project />}></Route>
      <Route path="*" element={<NoPage />} />
    </Routes>
  );
}

export default Main;
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router basename={`/${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}`}>
      <App /> {/* The various pages will be displayed by the `Main` component. */}
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Comment: Does this help answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/71985764/8690857 I think you just need to switch from `BrowserRouter` to `HashRouter` for Github compatibility.

Comment: Not quite. The homepage is correctly set as it does load and work as expected. The problem arises with the subpages. When I tried switching to HashRouter, all of my pages turned to blank pages. If I deleted the basename in ```<Router>``` then the home page would load, but the local links were no longer recognized and the link to the subpage just reloaded the homepage again.

Answer (score 1):

## Issues

Assuming your package.json file specifies a correct `homepage` entry, i.e. `"homepage": "https://myname.github.io/my-website"`, there are a couple issues.

1. Github pages don't work well with the `BrowserRouter`. Use the `HashRouter` instead.
2. Import and use the `Link` component to link to pages within the app. Using a raw anchor tag is likely sending a page request to the server for a sub-route that doesn't exist. (*This is why the `HashRouter` is necessary, BTW*)

## Updates

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { HashRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
      <App />
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

home.js

Replace the raw anchor tag and import and use the `Link` component that links to the `"/project"` route path.

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

...

<div>
  <Link to='/project'>
    <img alt='Project 1' src={Sunset} />
  </Link>
</div>
```

Comment: When I try this approach, having multiple pages works but the local references stop working. It is similar to this problem that I had: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73356326/local-page-links-a-href-arent-working-with-hashrouter/73363735#73363735

Comment: In addition to the above issue, when the browser loads the new link, it loads starting in the middle of the page instead of at the top.

Comment: @ChristopherOjo Oh, I was very close to commenting on your answer there. For that post the OP is having an issue using a hashlink to a section on the current page, not linking to any specific route. I *thought* I'd seen the code in your question somewhere before.

Comment: @ChristopherOjo Can you clarify what local references you are referring to in your comment above? For the scrolling you likely need to implement a [scrollToTop](/a/71390300/8690857) or similar.

Comment: Yeah, I thought your name looked familiar as well. I think the problem varies between each question because the approach is slightly different but the end goal remains the same.

Comment: by local references, I am referring to linking to a different area of the same page. For example, linking to an element further down the page.

Comment: @ChristopherOjo Oof, I just realized you *are* the OP for that other post. ‍♂️

Comment: @ChristopherOjo And yeah, these *are* two separate and independent issues.

Comment: Haha yeah, its been quite troublesome. I believed I have solved them both by switching to HashRouter and using the react-router-hash-link. I have also fixed the scrolling problem thanks to the scrollToTop link you posted in your earlier comment. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The solution was best described in this post in addition to doing what Drew Reese has commented.

[Use anchors with react-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40280369/use-anchors-with-react-router)

In summary:

You need to install react-router-hash-link.

```
npm install --save react-router-hash-link
```

Add `import { HashLink as Link } from 'react-router-hash-link';` to the page you use the links.

And use it as shown:

```
<Link className="nav-link" to="/#about-me">
  About Me
</Link>
```